# Angular JS Two-Way Binding with Dropdown in Grid

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, parse-platform, angularjs-scope

I am using AngularJS as well as Parse and the Parse-Angular-Patch. I have a sample app that does basic crud. [image: My CRUD app]

When I click the edit button. The Salutation loses it's state.
[image: My bug]

Here's the relevant HTML:

```
        <tbody data-ng-repeat-start="p in people" data-ng-data="who">
            <tr>
                <!-- Salutation -->
                <td style="min-width:95px;">
                    <span data-ng-hide="editRow == $index">{{p.get('salutation')}}</span>
                    <select data-ng-show="editRow == $index" data-ng-model="model.salutation" class="formControl" data-ng-options="s.label for s in salutations">
                        <option value="">--</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
             ...
                <!-- Action Buttons -->
                <td>
                    <button class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" data-ng-click="onEdit($index)" data-ng-hide="editRow==$index" style="min-width:70px;">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil "></span>&nbsp;edit
                    </button>
                    ...
```

You can see the full html at: https://github.com/arcnovus/learning-parse-angular-patch/blob/master/views/crud.html

Here's the relevant controller javascript:

```
$scope.onEdit = function (ix) {
        $scope.showAdd = false; // hide the add form
        $scope.editRow = ix; // set the index of the row being edited
        var currentPerson = $scope.people[ix]; // grab the current person object 
        $scope.model.fname = currentPerson.get('fname'); // update scope fname
        $scope.model.lname = currentPerson.get('lname'); // update scope lname
        $scope.model.salutation = currentPerson.get('salutation'); // BUG: this doesn't work and I don't know why, it should set the dropdown to the current salutation.
        $log.debug('cpsal: ' + currentPerson.get('salutation'));
        $log.debug('smsal: ' + $scope.model.salutation);
    };
```

When I look in the console to see the result of my $log.debug() statements, I see the following.

- cpsal: Dr.
- smsal: Dr.

Full source code for the controller here: https://github.com/arcnovus/learning-parse-angular-patch/blob/master/controllers/crud.js

The dropdown should have "Dr." selected. Any ideas on how to make this work?

Full project here: https://github.com/arcnovus/learning-parse-angular-patch

Comment: You seem to be filtering out some properties off of the salutations object array. What properties does s (i.e. s in salutations) have other than label? Does the currentPerson.get("salutation") call return the whole salutation object or only the label?

Comment: It's a Parse object so it has the default objectId, createdAt, updatedAt and ACL properties as well as the "label" property. In this context though all that matters is the label.  currentPerson.get("salutation") returns a string that represents the label.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have access to your Parse data, but I mocked up some static data and was able to get the list to populate and select the appropriate item in the list...

html:

```
     <select data-ng-show="editRow == $index" data-ng-model="model.salutation" class="formControl" data-ng-options="s.label as s.label for s in salutations">
          <option value="">--</option>
     </select>
```

data:

```
$scope.model = { salutation: 'Mr.', fname: 'Tom', lname: 'Jones' }; // our proxy object for the parse data we are crudding
$scope.people = [{salutation: 'Mr.', fname: 'Tom',lname: 'Jones'}];
$scope.salutations = [{label: 'Dr.'}, {label: 'Mr.'}];
```

Check the $scope.$watch function you have set up...it was clobbering the salutation in my mockup so I commented that out...make sure the same thing isn't happening when you are hooked up to Parse.

Comment: Commenting out the $watch doesn't help. If you point my project to an empty Parse App, it will create a salutations table and you should be able to see exactly what I see (if you're interested and you have a Parse account).

Since I can spit out the right values, I think the problem is that the binding is not firing properly for some reason. This is reinforced by the fact that I log every time the binding happens and when I click "edit" I don't see a log entry.

But forcing $scope.$apply() gives [apply already in progress error](http://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24apply).

Comment: Nevermind, the bind event _is_ firing; my $watch is on $scope.salutaion but I'm bound to $scope.model.salutation, that's why I saw nothing in the logs. Back to square one.

Comment: turns out all I needed to do was change the ng-options directive from

`"s.label for s in salutations"` 

to 

`"s.label as s.label for s in salutations"` 
like @terryt did in his example. Thanks @terryt!!!!